# How to calculate range() for the graph in Gremlin pagination query?

Tags: range, limit, gremlin, offset

How to calculate range() for the graph in `Gremlin pagination` query with input of page number and limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the page number starts with `1`, then

```
start_range = (page - 1 )* limit
end_range = start_range + limit

g.V('id').outE().hasLabel('created_by').range(start_range, end_range).inV()
```

For some reason, if the page number starts from `0`, then

```
start_range = page * limit
end_range = start_range + limit

g.V('id').outE().hasLabel('created_by').range(start_range, end_range).inV()
```

Comment: Just a comment to point out for anyone finding this answer that it's important to remember that `range` is inclusive/exclusive. So `range(0,2)` will get you the 0 and 1 results but not the 2 result.